# How to see the infinite case of "If $\cup_k I_k\subset I$, and the $I_k$ are disjoint, then $\sum_k|I_k|\le |I|$".

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I am reading Billingsley's *Probability and Measure*. Its Theorem 1.3(i) is

> If $\cup_k I_k\subset I$, and the $I_k$ are disjoint, then
> $\sum_k|I_k|\le |I|$.

The proof of the finite case is simple. But when it goes to the infinite case, the book says:

> *Infinite case*. If there are infinitely many intervals, each finite subcollection satisfies the hypotheses of the theorem, and so
> $\sum_{k=1}^n(b_k-a_k)\le b-a$ by the finite case. But as $n$ is
> arbitrary, the result follows.

I am confused, as $n$ is only finite, how it can be *arbitrary* and implies the *infinite* case? Is there a gap I missed?

Comment: There are only countably many intervals, you can enumerate them, then $\sum_{i =1}^{\infty}|I_i| =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i =1}^{n}|I_i|$.

Comment: @Michael, May I ask how we see there are only countably infinite intervals instead of uncountably infinite intervals? Is it because the formula $\cup_k I_k$?

Comment: @Xuchuang It's because they are disjoint intervals. Any collection of disjoint intervals is countable.

Comment: The fact that Billingsley writes $\sum_k |I_k|$ suggests he assumes the number of intervals is at most countably infinite.  You can prove that if $A$ is any collection of disjoint intervals (each of nonzero size) contained in some finite interval $[-M,M]$, then $A$ must be finite or countable: Write $A = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$ where $A_i$ is the subset of intervals of size $\geq 1/i$. Now each set $A_i$ is finite because it can contain at most $2Mi$ intervals. (This uses the fact about finite intervals that you are proving).

Comment: @Michael got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @bof thanks. I missed the modulus.